# how to get image from url in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one remote url which outputs the image
The url is in format like this

```
http://domain.com/my_file/view/<file_id>/FULL/
```

In the url "my_file" is a controller name, "view" is a function name and the other two are the parameters

If I hit this url in browser it shows me image

I want to take that image in my projects folder

I have tried with file_get_contents but it gives me warning with 404

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Give a real url maybe?

Comment: If the image is 404ing, then it either doesn't exist, or any clauses you've put in place to limit access to it (such as leech protection, limits based on user-agent / referrer) are not being met. Is this image on a server / host which you control?

Comment: give your real full image url your url must be http://domain.com/my_file/view/<file_id>/FULL/image.png or must be point to image name

Comment: You may need to parse the site for the real image link and use that instead of the link you provided

Comment: @seidr If I hit that image on browser then it is showing that image.

Comment: Provide us with the full URL then, because obviously there is something limiting access to it. Again, is this image on a server or site that you directly control, or is it on a third parties website? It's not quite so common these days, but some sites do implement leech protection based on various factors from the client. A request from file_get_contents will look completely different to a request from a browser.

Comment: @SnehalS Your browser might follow some redirections. `file_get_contents()` won't. If you gave us the full URL it would be way simpler, we cannot just guess what's the real problem here.

Comment: That'd make sense, but they'd be getting a 301 return code instead of a 404 in that case surely?

Answer (score 2):

```
$img=file_get_contents('http://example.com/image/test.jpg');
file_put_contents('/your/project/folder/imgname.jpg',$img);
```

This works only if `allow_url_fopen` is set to 1 in your php.ini file.
If you can change this value, enable it and you're done.

Another option is CURL. Check if this module is enabled in your PHP configuration.

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/image/test.jpg');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  $result = @curl_exec($ch);
  $curl_err = curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  if (empty($curl_err)) {
     file_put_contents('/your/project/folder/imgname.jpg',$result);
  }
```

If CURL is not enabled, your chance is to write a simple HTTP client like this:

```
  $buf='';
  $fp = fsockopen('example.com',80);
  fputs($fp, "GET /image/test.jpg HTTP/1.1\n" );
  fputs($fp, "Host: example.com\n" );
  fputs($fp, "Connection: close\n\n" );
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $buf .= fgets($fp,128);
  }
  fclose($fp);
  file_put_contents('/your/project/folder/imgname.jpg',$buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Curl for this:

function curlFile($url)
    {

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

function readurl()
{
$url="http://domain.com/my_file/view/<file_id>/FULL/";
curlFile($url);
}

echo readurl();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/my_file/view/<file_id>/FULL/');
if($image) file_put_contents('some/folder/<file_id>');
```

and it does not work, it probably means either:

1. That there is access control that prevents it on the remote server. In that case, you must set the appropriate cookies. I suggest using curl to do that.
2. The image path is wrong; try to view source when navigating to `http://domain.com/my_file/view/<file_id>/FULL/` using your browser.
3. The trailing / in your URL should not be there, e.g. `http://domain.com/my_file/view/<file_id>/FULL`?